# How to output event source Class Name in serilog RollingFile outputTemplate?

Tags: serilog

The `RollingFile.outputTemplate` that I am using for my sink in `<appSettings>` configuration is as below:

```XML
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />
```

The output log I am getting as:

`19:55:10 [Information] Application_Start...`

However, I want to also output the Class Name (source) from where the Log was generated, like -

`19:55:10 [Information] [Global.asax.cs] Application_Start...`

What should I add to the "value"? I added **[Source]** but is not working.

> value="{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] **[Source?]** {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The property name is called `SourceContext` - so:

```
value="{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

Comment: I added `[{SourceContext}]` property, but it is generating en empty bracket like - 

`14:53:41 [Information] [] Application_Start...` . What's wrong ? any idea?

Comment: You need to use `log.ForContext<T>()` to generate the property in the first place, it's not attached automatically

Comment: What if you want a custom name?  Wasn't clear [from source](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/serilog/serilog/src/Serilog.FullNetFx/Sinks/RollingFile/RollingFileSink.cs)

Comment: I just realized this was about the template _in_ the file; I meant the actual rolling file itself, like `log-{SourceContext}-{Date}.txt`

Comment: Example configuration: 

`Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\logs\path\log.txt"
                                    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();`


Example usage:

`Log.ForContext<ClassNameLoggingOccurringIn>().Error(e, "...");`