# Serilog custom context in rolling file name, Nlog context

Tags: c#, nlog, serilog

Similar to [How to output event source Class Name in serilog RollingFile outputTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094303/how-to-output-event-source-class-name-in-serilog-rollingfile-outputtemplate), but rather than within the log file (`outputTemplate`) I want to name the file.

Additionally, I was trying to switch between using `WriteTo.LiterateConsole + WriteTo.RollingFile` and `WriteTo.NLog`, maintaining that custom context.

However, to accomplish custom rolling file naming, I basically need to provide the name on logger initialization, like so:

```
var c = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithProperty(/* some standard stuff */)
    .WriteTo.LiterateConsole(minLevel)
    .WriteTo.RollingFile(string.IsNullOrEmpty(customName) ? "logs\log-{Date}.txt" : "logs\"+customName+".log.{Date}.txt") // <-- would have thought I could use `{SourceContext}` as placeholder...
    .CreateLogger()
    .ForContext(Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, customName) // <-- not sure if I need this here
    ;
```

I want to do something similar when attaching `NLog`, so I can take advantage of my existing NLog config line:

```
archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/${logger}.log.{#####}.txt"
```

with initialization like so:

```
var c = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithProperty(/* some standard stuff */)
    .Enrich.WithProperty(Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, customName) // <-- is this the trick?
    .WriteTo.Nlog(minLevel)
    .CreateLogger()
    .ForContext(Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, customName) // <-- not sure if this is redundant with enrichment above
    ;
```

Comment: It's a link-only answer, so I'll just comment, but I found this after finding your question: [Serilog Sinks ContextRollingFile](https://github.com/sschutten/serilog-sinks-contextrollingfile) - it looks promising.

Comment: The author of that link @sander-schutten actually answered my question, but a moderator deleted it?